# Setting nextFocus for EditTexts not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem with the `nextFocus...` attributes of `EditText`. First, I have a really hard time understanding which one of the `nextFocus...` parameters I'm supposed to use. When i press `Next` on my softkeyboard its looking for a next `EditText`, but how am i supposed to know if its looking down or up or wherever? I still have to specify the ID of the next View its going to focus, so why bother with directions at all?

Anyway, this is my layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTHgf.jpg

And when I edit Stacks I want the next `EditText` to be the Rest, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
stacks = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.calc_stacks_edit);
rest = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.calc_rest_edit);
stacks.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
stacks.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.calc_rest_edit);
rest.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

It still goes to the Amount `EditText` insead of Rest when Next button is pressed. What is the problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From XML set these attribs to stack.

```
  android:nextFocusForward="@+id/rest"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm doing in the code. And it doesn't work.

Comment: `first.setInputType(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT); first.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
first.setNextFocusForwardId(R.id.rest);`

If I try this from code it does not work, only the XML attribs do the trick for me.

Comment: [link](https://bitbucket.org/csenga/dialog-focus-test/overview)
Check this, it's working for me.

Comment: He's right, actually using actionNextd as imeOptions works.

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same problem and none of the solutions worked for me. I decided to focus forward programmatically. I created an extension fun for this.

```
/*
 * Sets manuel focus forward
 */
fun EditText.manualFocusForward(nextFocusView: View) {
    setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, event ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT
            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO
            || (event != null && event.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
        ) {
            nextFocusView.requestFocus()
            true
        } 

        false        
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
   inputViewCardNumber.editTextInput.manualFocusForward(inputViewExpDate.editTextInput)
```